# When I select a listview item in android the scrolling moves to top

Tags: android-listview, android-scrollbar

When I select a listview item in android the scrolling moves to top. That means the list view scrollbar should only move when I want it to. On selecting item, the scrollbar should stay where it was at the time of selection.